# How to set up a simple while loop to run a test from MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to run a simple test in mysql workbench.

I want to run 3 queries 1000 times in a loop, and I want to test this in 2 different configurations to see how they perform against each other.

Can I just run this test from mysql workbench? I'm getting syntax errors and assuming I can't use things like while loops directly within workbench.

Comment: You need to create a stored procedure, and then execute it. You can't directly run queries with loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you're running insert queries, you could do something like this:

Create your procedure:

```
create procedure load_user_test_data()
begin
declare v_max int default 1000;
declare v_counter int default 0;
  truncate table users;
  start transaction;
  while v_counter < v_max do
    # random query
    insert into users (username) values (CONCAT("user", floor(0 + (rand() * 65535))));
    set v_counter = v_counter + 1;
  end while;
  commit;
end
```

Call the procedure `call load_user_test_data`

Hopefully this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: OK. After over an hour of testing, I ended up (in phpMyAdmin) with: "_At `create procedure load_user_test_data() begin declare v_max int default 1000;` MySQL said: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`_". What am I missing?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem and the same error
It's been a while, but did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MySQL's

> **Benchmarks**

function. Hope it will help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html

Comment: The `BENCHMARK` function only works on expressions not entire queries.